# Solve redefinition of struct defined in two different OS-es

Tags: c, unit-testing

I have a project under QNX. I am trying to do unit-test (gtest) on it and I'm confronting with the following problem:

In one of my source files I use the **sigevent** structure from **sys/siginfo.h** (https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/s/sigevent.html).

In my unit-test I have created a stub file for the sys/siginfo.h file where I stubbed the sigevent structure but it complains of *redefinition* because *there is also a sigevent struct under linux* in 
[https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/**bits/siginfo.h**.html](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/siginfo.h.html).

The two stubs have different structure - I cannot use one instead of the other.
I cannot use namespaces because the sigevent struct is used in my source file and not in a stub file from unit-test - I'm not allowed to change the source file.

If I were to be able to change the source file, It would also have been impossible to fix this with namespaces since sys/siginfo.h is not a user-defined header. I think a solution would be a wrapper on sys/siginfo.h from QNX.

But how can solve this from unit-test?

**Errors:**

> /stubs/sys/siginfo.h:166:8: error: redefinition of 'struct sigevent' 
>   struct sigevent {
>
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/siginfo.h:320:16: error: previous
>   definition of 'struct sigevent'  typedef struct sigevent

P.S.: I tagged "C programming" for this issue because it's not entirely unit-test.

Thanks,
Carmen

Comment: so why do you stub a `sigevent` structure? If the structure is available at sysinfo.h on both systems? Why to stub it then?

Comment: Am I understanding you right that you are unit-testing in a test environment on Linux a file  (or group of files) from a project under QNX?

Comment: One solution could be to define in your project settings (IDE, makefile, whatever)  the combination of defines which protects Linux' `struct sigevent` (perhaps  __have_sigevent_t is enough).

Comment: Yes, @Peter-ReinstateMonica. The project runs under QNX and I'm doing unit-test in a test environment on Linux. I don't understand the solution you propose: 'to define the combination of defines which protects Linux struct sigevent'. Please describe!

Comment: @KamilCuk The sysinfo.h for QNX is only available when I run the project on QNX so it's not available in the test-environment. Therefore I have to stub it. And this goes into an error because Linux has his own version of stub.

Comment: `so it's not available in the test-environment`  What is your test environment? `there is also a sigevent struct under linux in` Well, so if your test environment is linux, sysinfo.h is available. And it's also available on QNX. So....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only tentative but it is too long for a comment.

The situation is: You have a piece of software you want to test which is designed to run under QNX, on some embedded device. It uses `struct sigevent` whose actual definition is system dependent. You have written a mock mimicking QNX's version of it, for test purposes and in order to be system independent.

Now you write a module test in a software environment under Linux.

My first question is how you prevent duplicate definitions of `struct sigevent` when you eventually compile your program under QNX (I assume you are not cross-compiling under Linux). Preventing this should be similar to preventing it under Linux. (If you actually are cross-compiling you need to fix that cross-compiling environment; it should come with its own system library catering to QNX and not by default include Linux headers.)

Linux comes with its own `struct sigevent` which now collides with yours. I assume that the structure definition is included indirectly by e.g. `signal.h`, a header which, I assume, you need. (You should perhaps first find out whether you really need the offensive header at all; maybe you have superfluous includes in your file.)

The easiest case is if the struct definition comes in its own header, which then has its own include guard, e.g. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/types/sigevent_t.h.html.

You would simply define `__sigevent_t_defined` on top of your source file, which would be transitively visible in all included headers and prevent inclusion of that header file (and thus a redefinition of `struct sigevent`):

```
#define __sigevent_t_defined
#include <signal.h> // or whatever
//...
struct sigevent { /* mock definition, no collision */ };
```

One possible issue here is that code in other headers may access members of the original struct which your mock does not contain. Worse, Linux library code may find an unexpected layout of `struct sigevent` (it was compiled with a different struct definition, after all). You cannot use a Linux library function with your `struct sigevent`, also not indirectly (if it is included in a larger structure). But with a unit test you may not have to.

I have seen another version of `sruct sigevent` which was part of a larger header and "protected" by some combination of #defines, but I cannot find it right now. The error message of your compiler should tell you where the conflicting definition is located; take a look at it and find out what you must define to make that struct definition "invisible".

Comment: The bits/siginfo.h is included directly or indirectly in gtest/gtest.h which I included in the main test file. I do not have to choose between linux or qnx files when compiling the project under qnx.

Comment: I have defined the _SYS_WAIT_H guard before including gtest/gtest.h file and the problem is solved. Indeed, I might need this file (wait.h) in unit-test in the future so I will need to find a more specific file to exclude... Thank you!